# getting started with flask

Tags: python, flask

I was starting with flask and wanted to check out how active the community is. However I am unable to find any google group for flask?

Comment: They do not have any google group. They have mailing list and irc which is clearly mentioned on their site. Moreover this is not the right type of question to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no google groups. There's a couple of other channels they use though, you'll find them here: http://flask.pocoo.org/community/